# Rails 3 tag_list.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, each, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a problem trying to make a list from a acts_as_taggable_on  tag_list
I have tag list array, and I want to list it so im trying this:

```
<%= proyects.tag_list.each do |tagsx| %>
* <%= tagsx %>  <br>
<% end %>
```

And I get the list im looking for, but also the whole array again... 
When it renders, looks like this..

```
* AJAX
* Rails
* Heroku
* Prototype
AJAX, Rails, Heroku, Prototype
```

Any ideas on getting rid of the last line? 
Or do you guys know a more efficient way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= proyects.tag_list.each do |tagsx| %>
```

to this:

```
<% proyects.tag_list.each do |tagsx| %>
```

You don't want to output the return value of the `.each` call, just the elements of the array. Calling [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) with a block returns the array (as you are):

> **each {|item| block } → ary**
>   **each → an_enumerator**
>   Calls *block* once for each element in `self`, passing that element as a parameter.
>   If no *block* is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

and that's were the comma delimited list is coming from.

Comment: I knew it was something like that, thank you very much, I've been working on this problem all day.

Answer (score 1):

because you have a typo in your code :-)

```
<%- proyects.tag_list.each do |tagsx| %>
* <%= tagsx %>  <br>
<% end %>
```

see the difference?

no '=' after the first % sign

%= means that the result of a Ruby expression is returned to the view

%- means that the Ruby expression is evaluated, but no result is returned

The code in your question gets "proyects.tag_list" , executes the loop, during which it prints out the individual tags, and then returns the whole array to the view because of the '='